# Magento + jquery slider $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, magento

I'm integrating a content slider into magento theme, but having some issue with the js.
I get the error "$ is not defined", then I found a solution from a website stating that I should add this line "jQuery.noConflict();" into my jquery file.

Then in the home.phtml, :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $s = jQuery.noConflict();
    $s(document).ready(function(){
        $("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
    });
</script>
```

In my page.xml, this is how I include the js

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-ui.min.js</script></action>

<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
```

After I done the above changes, I get the error "jQuery is not defined"

Appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

EDITED :
This problem is solved by calling the js from the CMS page->content :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
   var $j = jQuery.noConflict();  jQuery(document).ready(function($) { jQuery("#featured  ul").tabs({fx:{opacity:"toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true); }); //  &gt;
// ]]></script>
```

At the CMS page -> Design , include the js files needed :-

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/slider.css</name></action>
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-ui.min.js</name></action>
</reference>
```

However this method is only useful if only a particular page is using the js and not every page. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is a better alternative to what Mathew is suggesting.

Use a closure to limit the scope of $, in your example you would need to change the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
```

To something such as:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Also, you need to put those addJs calls into reference 'head' to put them in the right place in the HTML source. Right now, they are probably in the root block instead.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply. I have tried your suggestion but I am still getting the error "jQuery is not defined". Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks. I'm sorry but I don't understand the last part "you need to put those addJs calls into reference 'head' to put them in the right place in the HTML source. Right now, they are probably in the root block instead." 

Do you mean I should put the js in the .phtml instead?

Comment: @Sylph, no: you added those addJs action calls in page.xml, but not inside the correct block, you need to put them in reference 'head'.

Comment: Many thanks Daniel, I took another approach is by entering from the CMS Layout Update XML , the reference head and copied the js to the skin path. The error of jQuery is not defined is gone now, just that the slideshow is still not working. I will try to solve it from here. Appreciate your help! :)

Comment: I have posted the solution above. Thanks a lot again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following code at the end of  **/template/page/html/head.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Use jQuery instead of $ in your script files.
Your code look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          jQuery("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity:"toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, 
 true);
      }); 
 </script>
```

jquery 1.5.2v works well with magento.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi blakcaps, thanks for your reply. I put it script in "header.phtml" coz I don't have a head.phtml. Still the same error though "jQuery is not defined". :(

Comment: Copy the head.phtml from base theme and put it in your theme directory and try.Dont add script in header.phtml

Comment: Hi blakcaps. Many thanks. I have done so at the site, but still the same error. It seems like it could not get the jquery at all? Then I went to the js file and "alert('aa')" , I actually able to get the alert box, meaning the file is being called.

Comment: You have added alert to which js file.Are you still getting "jQuery is not defined" error

Comment: ya, unsure why. I took another approach is entering the path from Layout Update XML from the CMS and copied the js files to the skin path. The error has disappeared but the slideshow is still not working. I will try to solve it from here. Many thanks for your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: have posted the solution above. The slideshow is working fine now. Many thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change all instances of the $ in your script to use jQuery(). For more information see the documents:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Alternatively you can use the mXperts plugin for the job:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mxperts/extension/1619/mxperts--jquery-base

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your reply. I have changed the instances, but I get the error "jQuery is not defined" :(

Comment: IMHO it is difficult to get right. The MxPerts solution is probably your best way forward as you can paste your scripts in the admin and it does the $ -> jQuery for you. You will need to remove your header scripts and leave it to the plugin.

Comment: Have you called jQuery.noConflict() ? You may also try including prototype first.

Comment: Hi Mathew, thanks a lot for your comment :D
Hi Gordon, thanks for your comment too. I have tried changing the position (callng prototype first then jquery), but to no avail.
I called jQuery.noConflict() but still getting the same error, "jQuery is not defined". I'm kinda stuck.. lol >"<

Comment: Thanks for the link Mat, but I do not want to use extension for this particular one coz I will need to use jquery as and when, and the extension does not support all the jquery functions. :) Have managed to solve the issue. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`. This code goes in your script, and  use `$j` in place of `$`.